# Total vs. Average/Expected internal energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry

Total internal energy and average/expected internal energy are used interchangeably, which causes a lot of confusion for me.

Is
$$
U = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i E_i,
$$ the weighted sum of the energy states of a system, describing the total internal energy or the average? If it is the average, what does that really mean?

It wouldn't make sense if it was the total, since the equation is independent of the number of particles/molecules in they system, but I just want to be sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I have edited your question to include your equation in MathJax, rather than as an image.  If you stick around and ask further questions (and we hope that you do), please use MathJax rather than images, as it helps accessibility.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert will do!

Comment: "Total internal energy and average/expected internal energy are used interchangeably," Who says that? Give a source for your assertion please. No reliable text do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a formula for the average (mean) of $N$ energy states.  Presumably $p_i$ is the probability that the system is in energy state $E_i$.

You might have seen the mean worked out as $\frac{\Sigma fx}{\Sigma f}$ where $f$ is frequency.  In that case the top line is the total, but when divided by the denominator it gives the mean.

Your formula is similar to that, when dealing with probabilities the bottom line is $\Sigma 
 p_i$  and that's $1$.

Comment: I thought that as well, but I wasn't too sure. Some texts would talk about the total energy, and then would jump to the expression above without emphasizing a difference.

Does that mean the expression is for the expected energy state for any one particle? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, seems so, as long as the $p_i$ are the probabilities that the particle can take the corresponding energy states, you're welcome!

Comment: They are, thanks again!